# While reading a file in c++, how does it automatically puts char in character array and numbers in integer variable?

Tags: c++, file-handling

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

class akh {
public:
    char name[20];
    int age;
};

int main() {
    akh ak;
    cout << "Size of ak:" << sizeof(ak) << endl;
    fstream fout("abc.dat", ios::binary | ios::out);
    cout << "\nEnter your name: ";
    cin.getline(ak.name, 20);
    cout << "\nEnter your age: ";
    cin >> ak.age;

    fout.write((char*) &ak, sizeof(ak));
    fout.close();

    fstream fin("abc.dat", ios::in | ios::binary);
    fin.read((char*)&ak, sizeof(ak)); // automatically puts name in ak.name and age in ak.age ? How is this happening?
    cout << "\nName: " << ak.name;
    cout << "\nAge: " << ak.age;
    fin.close();

    return 0;
}
```

1. How is this happening? Also if i have "myName19" in text file and
   begin reading, then it automatically put myName in char and 19 in
   integer variable.
2. After closing the file, tellg pointer automatically moves to the beginning of 
   the file?
3. Is there any other method to read and write in binary file except 
   ((char*)&x,sizeof(x))??

Answer (score 0):

> 1. How is this happening?

You are writing the complete memory layout of class `akh` to the binary file as is.
So if you read it back in the same manner, and with the same number of bytes, you will have the same memory layout in the `ak` instance.

> 2. After closing the file, tellg pointer automatically moves to the beginning of the file?

No, there's no more `tellg` pointer maintained after you call `close()`.

For input you are opening a new `fstream` instance `fin`, which starts reading from the beginning of the file.

> 3. Is there any other method to read and write in binary file except ((char*)&x,sizeof(x))??

For binary files no. As mentioned before, you want to write and read the exact number of bytes how they laid out in memory.

If you want to have human readable characters in a text file use the formatted text operators `<<` for output, and `>>` for input.

---

When I run your code, the problem you have becomes clear. The `std::getline()` variant you are using, takes exactly 20 characters from the input to `ak.name`:

```
cin.getline(ak.name, 20);
```

You can fix that by replacing the above line with

```
cin >> ak.name;
```

and put a space between name and age when inputting.

[Here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/65faf33a8c7277e5)'s a solution where everything works as intended, and shows the memory layout of your binary file.